# How to display inline Autocomplete component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to display **inline** the Autocomplete component, either alonside other Autocomplete components and/or any other React MUI components.

Starting from the example about countries from the [doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#country-select):

[image: Edit CountrySelect Material Demo]

In index.js my *first* attempt was the following:

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Demo from "./demo";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <Demo />
    <Demo />
    <TextField />
    <TextField />
  </StyledEngineProvider>
);
```

with this outcome:

[image: Inline test]

As you can see, while a component like TextField is automatically displayed inline, we cannot say the same thing for Autocomplete.

So, my *second* attempt was to force the inline property by a Box as shown in the [doc](https://mui.com/system/display/#inline):

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { StyledEngineProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Demo from "./demo";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <Box component="div" sx={{ display: 'inline' }}><Demo /></Box>
    <Box component="div" sx={{ display: 'inline' }}><Demo /></Box>
    <TextField />
    <TextField />
  </StyledEngineProvider>
);
```

**Result**: even in this case nothing changed.

I cannot figure out what is wrong. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You may give a try to `Stack` Component available in [doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/#main-content).

```
<Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
    <Demo />
    <Demo />
</Stack>
```

Edit:

I have looked at your `Demo.js` and found this solution. It may help you.
Adding this line in `<Autocomplete>`
`sx={{display : 'inline-flex', width : '50%' }}` 
may solve your problem as it does in sandbox.
Here's [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/countryselect-material-demo-forked-0nsqvn?file=/index.js).

Also width may cause problem.